# React map and dynamic Inputfields based on Array value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i'm totally new in React / JS / JSX programming and struggling the last days with a map()

I want to create a amount on  Fields based on the value of "exercise_sets" of an Array

exercises-Array:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Push Volume","exercises":[{"exercise_id":1,"exercise_sets":3},{"exercise_id":2,"exercise_sets":2}],"total_exercises":2]
```

I can already loop through "exercies" with map()

```
return (
    <ScrollView>
        
        {map(exercises, (item, i) => (


<Text>{item.exercise_title}</Text>

 ))}

    </ScrollView>
  );
```

Now i want to create, in this case 3 TextInputs like the following, inside the map (-> exercise_sets = 3 on first exercise)

```
<TextInput name={`Reps-${item.exercise_title}-{i}`} placeholder={item.exercise_sets} mode="flat" autoCapitalize="none" style={Styles.AuthInput} />
```

Tried so many things but without success, hopefully someone can give me a hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in order to dinamically generate the TextInputs you have to make a for loop inside your first map.

Something like this.

```
return (
  <ScrollView>
    {exercises.map((exercise, index) => (
      <View key={exercise.id}>
        <Text>{exercise.title}</Text>
        {Array.from({ length: exercise.exercise_sets }).map((_, setIndex) => (
          <TextInput
            key={`Reps-${exercise.title}-${setIndex}`}
            name={`Reps-${exercise.title}-${setIndex}`}
            placeholder={`Set ${setIndex + 1}`}
            mode="flat"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            style={Styles.AuthInput}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
);
```